# Как сделать номер телефона в UITextfield без кода города?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Например, я хочу вставить номер (+999) 98-9999999 из «Контакты» в UITextField, но без знака «+» и кода города. Можно ли обойтись без таких библиотек, как "PhoneNumberKit" и т. Д.?

Answer (score 0):

Нужны правила форматирования номера и что должно получиться. Можно при вставке простейшим образом проверять и подменять на нужное:

```swift
textField.addTarget(
    self,
    action: #selector(onTextChanged(_:)),
    for: .editingChanged
)

@objc private func onTextChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // Здесь любые правила,
    // которые необходимы для форматирования/проверки номера.
    // К примеру, удалить `-`:
    // sender.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    // Для примера оставлено только цифры и последние 9 символов из них:
    guard let text = sender.text else {
        return
    }
    let newText = text.replacingOccurrences(
        of: #"\D"#,
        with: "",
        options: .regularExpression,
        range: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex
    ).suffix(9)
    textField.text = String(newText)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Также эту логику можно использовать в delegate UITextField в методе shouldChangeCharactersIn?  Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Gwyn , конечно. С поправками на replacement string и заменяемый range подогнать под свои нужды.